# How to use NOINDEX,FOLLOW with paginated results except index page

Tags: seo, meta-tags, web-crawlers, pagination

I am running a classified website. **At the moment I am using lazy loading with jquery to load content while scrolling**.

> I got to know that using jquery loading is not good for search-engine
>   bots and java-script disabled web browsers.

So I added pagination links to appear if the javascript are disabled.I use same page(index.php) to generate paginated results as follows,

```
1st page --->http://www.example/classified/index.php
2nd page --->http://www.example/classified/index.php?page_id=2
3rd page --->http://www.example/classified/index.php?page_id=3 ....etc
```

***I don't want to add paginated results to search engines.But I need my index.php to be in search engines***.

So as for some articles I decided to use **"noindex,follow"** in the meta robots tag in index.php.But as for my knowledge this will also skip indexing the index.php also.

What my problem is will it work? or what should I do for index my index.php without paginated results in search engines?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I don't want to add paginated results to search engines. But I need my index.php to be in search engines.***

If you want `index.php` to be indexed, but the paginated links not to be indexed, then `noindex,follow` will do the opposite:  The `noindex` tells search engines not to index the page, and the `follow` tells them to follow links on the page.

To tell search engines to index the page but not to follow links on it, use: `index,nofollow`. For more information, see [this](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?csw=1) from Google, and [What is NoIndex / Follow and when do I need it?](http://dan-nolan.com/what-is-noindex/) *(from a different Dan)*.

Alternatively, you can disallow paginated URLs from being indexed in your *robots.txt*:

```
Disallow: /*?page_id=
```

Comment: No problem, hope it helped :-)